# select row with max of a variable in one step

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which looks something like this:

```
--------EXAMPLE---------------------------------------------------------
Cat1           Cat2          Value
a              NULL          131
b              e1            143
a              e2            135
c              NULL          136
a              e1            132
a              NULL          13
c              e4            1
```

I want to select the row from above which has the highest value for various types in Cat1. So, my answer would look like the following:

```
--------EXAMPLE---------------------------------------------------------
Cat1           Cat2          Value
b              e1            143
a              e2            135
c              NULL          136
```

I am using Microsoft SQL and I am looking for something efficient as I have about 40 million rows in my table that needs manipulation.

Thanks!!

Comment: Correlated Subqueries http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` with `DENSE_RANK`:

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT cat1, 
                cat2, 
                Value, 
                Rank = Dense_rank() 
                         OVER ( 
                           partition BY cat1 
                           ORDER BY Value DESC) 
         FROM   dbo.tablename) 
SELECT cat1, 
       cat2, 
       value 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  rank = 1
```

Use `Row_Number` instead of `Dense_Rank` if you just want a single (arbitrary) record if there are multiple records with the same highest value.